# UITextField Validation not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, validation, uibutton, uitextfield

I am new to iPad developer,

I am making Registration form in my iPad, when user click Submit button i want to validate my textfield whether it is empty or not, if it is empty then it will display alert **No cannot be empty.**

here is my code snippet but it is not working,

***declaration:***

```
UITextField* noTxtbox= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 200, 180, 50)];
noTxtbox.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:noTxtbox];
```

***Code:***

```
if ([noTxtbox.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your No !"
                                                            message:nil delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
    }
```

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: how do you add your textfield? if its by xib, make sure you connect your outlet

Comment: adding programmatically, see my new EDIT

Comment: Try with `if([noTxtBox.text length] == 0)`

Comment: Try self.noTxtbox.text, instead of noTxtbox.text

Comment: have you set the delegate of the alertView?

Comment: add NSLog inside your if

Comment: @tarheel `self.noTxtBox` will not work, he is not declaring it as a property.

Comment: @iNoob. Put that up there before he clarified it wasn't a property, but yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `noTxtbox.text.length == 0`

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be due to white space. Check it by removing white space by :-

```
NSString * noTxtbox_text = [noTxtbox.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([noTxtbox_text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your No !"
                                                        message:nil delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```